# Check if mysql user exists

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$check="SELECT * FROM users WHERE name = '$_POST[name]'";
$rs = mysqli_query($conn,$check);
$data = mysqli_fetch_array($rs, MYSQLI_NUM);
if($data[0] > 1) {
    echo "User Already in Exists<br/>";
}else
    echo "User does Not exist";
```

Is this the correct way? It says User does Not exist no matter what; and I know there is a user named "test" in the db.

Comment: What id `$data[0]` ?

Comment: if(mysqli_num_rows($rs) > 0) { echo "user exists; }

Comment: ... or even `SELECT COUNT(*) ... `

Comment: ... or even `SELECT 1`

Comment: @Phil: it's not as semantic as `COUNT(*)`

Comment: @zerkms I disagree. If we're just checking if a record exists or not, why bother with a count?

Comment: @Phil: because it answers the question "how many rows we have with the given `name`"

Comment: @zerkms I don't see that question in this, err, question ;)

Comment: @Phil: "if user exists" ≡ "if there is 1 row with the given name"

Comment: I guess this question can be closed as "Primarily opinion-based" ;) So many ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
// this line makes mysqli throw exceptions so you'll never have to check
// return values for false
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

// prepare a statement checking for existence
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE name = ?');

// bind the POST param to the parameter
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['name']);
$stmt->execute();

// if there are any rows, that means the name exists
if ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo 'User "', htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']), '" already exists<br/>';
} else {
    echo 'User "', htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']), '" does not exist<br/>';
}
```

Comment: It works! But why was the way I was doing it incorrect?

Comment: @HuangLee My guess would be that you had no way of knowing what column was going to be in position 0 of the result set because you were using `SELECT *` and whatever it was, when compared to `> 1`, was evaluating to `false`

Comment: @HuangLee Also, your original code was vulnerable to SQL injection. Using a prepared statement with bound parameters avoids that issue